# Logging calls after hanging up on smart phones

Tags: logging, mobile

In the various smartphone APIs/SDKs, I was wondering if it is possible to prompt a user if they'd like to log a phone call after they hang up. The most basic functionality would be after calling out or receiving a call, the phone would ask

> Do you want to log the call to|from 555-555-5555?
> Yes | No | Never this number

(then it might take the user to a small form and then post the info to a webservice)

The business use is for lawyers who have company phones and need to track billing.

This is a bit different question than [Accessing the iPhone's Call log with the iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341622/accessing-the-iphones-call-log-with-the-iphone-sdk).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On an Android phone you can register a [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) to receive a notification of when a call hangs up and log the number by whatever method you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Blackberries have call logging out of the box. Blackberry Enterprise Server activated units sync the log with the server.

Comment: Cool, do you know if there is there a way to hook into an event to interject a dialog of sorts?

Answer (score 1):

On iPhone, ***no way.***
Apple would have to allow (shudder) background applications.

Note: Shraptnel is right, you may be able to monitor the phone state with some private API's if you jailbroke your phone and ran your program in the background.