# How I can access the call log/history of iPhone

Tags: iphone, logging, iphone-sdk-3.0, call, jailbreak

This is for jailbroken iPhone.

Is there a way I can access the call_history.db on iPhone which is a database where apple logs the phone call information.

It is stored at /private/var/mobile/Library/CallHistory directory. When I try to enumerate directory paths under /private/var/mobile/Library it does not list CallHistory folder but everything else. I guess Apple does allow access somehow despite of having all the permissions.

Is there a way I can get access to call_history.db and copy it under my app?

I have already gone through another stackoverflow question here [Accessing the iPhone's Call log with the iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341622/accessing-the-iphones-call-log-with-the-iphone-sdk) but no luck so far :(

Comment: If you know the path of the file, can't you just copy it to a different location and read it from there?  Or does the copy itself fail?

Comment: Yes, the copy itself fails. I tried to print all the folders under /private/var/mobile/Library (Where the CallHistory folder resides) on the console. It does not pring the CallHistory folder. Only Preferences, Keyboard and AddressBook directories are logged on the console. But when see using winSCP or cyberduck on the ssh gui, I can see lot of folders there.

Comment: See the link below it describes in way better way: Link1:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498291/iphone-unable-to-open-database-file-for-call-history-db-in-xcode-app Link2:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214725/iphone-call-log-history

Comment: Have a look at this link, this website challenge this functionality

https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/

Answer (score 1):

it is located in 
/private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory

if you ssh into the phone through terminal, and you enter

find | grep "name of file you are looking for(case sensitive)"

It'll normally pull it up for you.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 11-13, it is located at `/var/mobile/Library/CallHistoryDB`

[image]