# iPhone "unable to open database file" for call_history.db in xcode app

Tags: iphone, sqlite, jailbreak

I am trying to access database call_history.db in jailbroken iPhone. I am able to access call_history.db for iPhone 4 with iOS 4.1. But the problem is I am not able to access the database in iPhone 3gs with iOS 3.1.3.

When I try to open the database for 3gs I get the following database error:

> unable to open database file

I use different paths for iOS 4.1 and iOS 3.1.3

- iOS 4.1 in iPhone 4 - /private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db
- and iOS 3.1.3 in iPhone 3gs - /private/var/mobile/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db

### Update

I fetch the call_history.db in the following way

```
//NSString *path=@"/private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db";//for ios 4.0 and above call_history.db
 NSString *path=@"/var/mobile/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db";//for ios 3.0 and above call_history.db

if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
   //code for fetching the calls goes here.////

    NSLog(@"call_history present");
}

else {

    NSLog(@"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Here the output is the error:

> unable to open Database file

I noticed that I am not able to access the Library folder in both iPhone's through the above code. I am able to retrieve all the file manually through ssh.

Comment: i also checked for the sms.db file. In iphone 4 i am able to access the call_history.db file located at /private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db , but i am not able to access sms.db which is located at /private/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db . So i am thinking it might be some thing to do with the file location. but am not sure what is happening her. can somebody plz help

Comment: i noticed that i am unable to access /private/var/mobile/Library folder from coding. i also checked the permissions for the mobile/Library folder and it is same as wireless/Library folder. Then too its not accessible. does nybody has an idea bout this????

Comment: Share some of the code you are using. Because if your Phone is jailbroken, you should be able to access the directories without error.

Comment: @ WrightsCS : i have edited my question with the code. i use the simple sqlite_open statement to open the database files. It works for ios 4 with wireless folder, but it doesnt work for ios 3.1.3 where the call_history.db is located in Library folder.

Comment: it looks like the UNIX owner of the sms.db is "mobile" while the owner of call_history.db is "wireless". Maybe that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 5):

Your app is in a sandbox, which is not able to access anything outside of itself. Suppose your targeting jailbroken devices, this is another story.

Xcode will install your app into a sandboxed environment. You need to manually sign the app using **`ldid -S /YourApp.app/YourApp`** then copy it tom the devices `/Applications` directory.

Comment: i am working on a jailbroken device. but still am not able to access the Library folder where the files like SMS, Notes, Calendar etc are present.what could be the reason for this, Do u think my device might not be jailbroken properly???

Comment: No. If you are installing your app through xcode onto your device it will install it as a sandboxed app. You need to manually sign it using LDID and copy it to the /Applications directory.

Comment: can u tell me how should i go about doing this?? how should i manually sign it using LDID??

Comment: i did what u suggested. i did ldid on my .app, then copied the .app file to /Applications folder. But i still dont think it worked. how can i debug the app which is inside /Applications???

Comment: moreover the app crashes on the launch itself. i doesnt go any further.

Comment: Jayshree: Check the syslog to see why it crashed. It could be because it's either not properly pseudo signed, or because your code doesn't expect to live in /Applications.

Comment: Jayshree, like rpetrich says, you probably didnt sign it correctly, if  you get a SINGNAL 9 in the syslog, then thats your problem. Also, the only way to debug the app while its in /Applications is by using NSLOG throughout your code or when your app crashes check the console to see whats happening.

Comment: Have a look at this link, this website challenge this functionality

https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/

Answer (score 0):

This was the best and easy tutorials i have seen
http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

Instead of hard coding the path, try below.

```
databaseName = @"AnimalDatabase.sql";

// Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
```

Comment: yes, but in my this case i need to access the call_history.db which resides outside our Application's directory. Your code will fetch the files which is inside the Application's directory only. call_history.db's path is given in my question itself.

Comment: besides i dont think this is a problem with sqlite queries, i think it has more to do with sandboxing.

Comment: I mean to say instead of hardcoding the paths you can get the path dynamically                   ios 4.1 in iphone 4 - /private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db

and ios 3.1.3 in iphone 3gs - /private/var/mobile/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db

Comment: I understood what u meant, but NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomain returns only the document or Library folder from Application Folder. Do u have code sample to fetch /private/var/mobile/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db. using NSSearchPath ???