# Get Call log details from NonJailbreakenIPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5

Is it possible to get call log details (Received, Dailed and missed) from NonJailbreakenIPhone? 
I follow this link http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/ 
but i didn't get any thing.
If possible please provide some code or steps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can access the call log/history of iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817813/how-i-can-access-the-call-log-history-of-iphone)

Comment: @Cyrille I don't think this is a dupe because that question specifically asks for a solution when jailbroken.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is impossible because of the way apps are sandboxed on iOS.  While it might have been possible in previous iOS versions, iOS 5+ have locked down file system access to only within your own app's bundle.