# I want to access call log of iphone can this is possible

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to developed a application in iphone with objective-c that is retrieve all call     details That we can show incoming, outgoing and Missed call. can this is possible that we can do this.

Comment: Did you attempt to search google with your question? http://www.google.com/search?q=iphone+programming+access+call+log You'll find more than enough answers to this question, many even on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341622/accessing-the-iphones-call-log-with-the-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 3):

No, in a non-jailbroken device, with the public API, we can't do this.