# How to get last dialled number or call logs in iPhone Programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can somebody help me in getting the last dialled number or call logs in iPhone Programmatically?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing the iPhone's Call log with the iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341622/accessing-the-iphones-call-log-with-the-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 2):

This is not available in the iPhone SDK.