# How to Access iPhone Call Log History on iOS5

Tags: ios5, calllog, recent-screens

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing the iPhone's Call log with the iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341622/accessing-the-iphones-call-log-with-the-iphone-sdk)

I am currently doing an address book application, I want to have a 'Recents' call logs. I am now using Xcode 4.3.3 and developing app in iOS 5.1.0 and 5.1.1.. It seems that call_history.db was not already supported by apple in this version, I see some discussions regarding this matter.

Do you have any knowledge in call history logs where I can apply it in iOS 5?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no ways of doing it in iOS 5. and your App may get rejected by Apple also.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible in legal way, you can do it by using private framework, but your application will be rejected