# Is it possible to log phone calls and messages on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I would like to log and than send to my server following information:

**Phone calls**

- date and time

  - start of call
  - end of call
- contact / phone number

**Messages (SMS)**

- message text
- receive date and time
- contact / phone number

Comment: Did you read documentation? Did you [Google/Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341622/accessing-the-iphones-call-log-with-the-iphone-sdk) first before asking question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to access the native api for phone calls or sms